# Java interferface with Generic class and its implementation

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a interface named ReportWriter, which write report to OutputStream, the Report class which contains list of reportRow, the is also an abstract class:

```
public interface ReportWriter<T extends ReportRow> {
    OutputStream writeReport(Report<T> report) throws ReportWriterException;
}

public abstract class Report<T extends ReportRow> {
   private List<T> rows = Lists.newArrayList();
   ...
}

public abstract class ReportRow {...}
```

Now i have CsvWriter which implement ReportWriter,

```
public class CsvWriter<T extends ReportRow> implements ReportWriter {
        @Override
        public ByteArrayOutputStream writeReport(Report report) throws ReportWriterException {
        ...
         for (T row : report.getRows()) {  <-- incompatible type
               ..write here..
         }
}
```

in the above code, it complains incompatible type:

```
require Object found T.
```

I dont' understand in Report class I've specified the T is a subclass of ReportRow, why I got this complain?

Then I tried to update the CsvWriter's writeReport as below:

```
public class CsvWriter<T extends ReportRow> implements ReportWriter {
   @Override
   public ByteArrayOutputStream writeReport(Report<T> report) throws ReportWriterException {  <--- complain here
...
}
```

now it complained:

```
writeReport(Report<T> report) clashes with writeReport(Report report); both methods have same erasure.
```

How can i fix this? thanks

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you're mixing parameterized types and raw types. You should probably read [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the interface you're implementing with the generic type:

```
public class CsvWriter<T extends ReportRow> implements ReportWriter<T> {
```

(note the `ReportWriter<T>`)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't test this yet, but likely it's because you used a raw type when inheriting.  Try this for your second code block:

```
public class CsvWriter<T extends ReportRow> implements ReportWriter<T> {...
```

Note the extra `<T>` on ReportWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about this snippet:

```
public class CsvWriter<T extends ReportRow> implements ReportWriter {
    @Override
    public ByteArrayOutputStream writeReport(Report report) throws ReportWriterException {
        ...
        for (T row : report.getRows()) {  <-- incompatible type
        ..write here..
    }
}
```

Without a generic type argument, the `ReportWriter` you are extending becomes a `ReportWriter<ReportRow>`. That means `report.getRows()` will return a `List<ReportRow>`.

But you're trying to assing it's elements to a variable of the type `T`. Which is `T extends ReportRow`. So `T` might be a subclass of `ReportRow`.

If it is, you're performing an implicit downcast, so the compiler throws an error.

---

By extending `ReportWriter<T>` instead, `getReport()` will now return a `List<T>`, and it's elements are safe to assign to variables of type `T` (obviously).